# Scrollbar changes colors on hover in Chrome

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm getting a weird issue in Chrome when I mouse over a `div`. The scrollbar changes to some strange colors, but only on hover. Here's a screenshot (left is normal, right is hover):

[image: left scrollbar looks normal; right is painted in an unusual mix of red, yellow and dark blue]

I'm not trying to style the scrollbars or anything, so I have no idea why this would be happening. It's only happening on XP, too, which is really weird. I'm guessing it's a Chrome bug, but maybe not. The only weird thing about this is that it's in a drop down menu, but that shouldn't mess it up like that.

EDIT: It only happens on this particular scrollbar, not on any other scrollbar.

EDIT 2: Restarting didn't help.

EDIT 3: It happens on any computer with Chrome and XP. <strike>I'll try to put a demo together but it's kind of a semi-confidential internal thing at the moment.</strike> Here's a demo: http://www.weblinxinc.com/bug/

EDIT 4: Removed CSS3 transitions, still a problem.

Comment: Did you restart?  It looks more like a window manager issue.

Comment: Can you provide a link so we can test?

Comment: Restarted, did nothing. Also posted about the demo, I'll try and get something together but I can't really post the full thing.

Comment: Semi-confidential? Please, no one here is going to "steal" your CSS, either post a way to reproduce this or it didn't happen. Did you try removing all CSS so that you can at least know if it's a CSS issue?

Comment: That particular element has `-webkit-transition` set, correct? Transitions trigger hardware acceleration in Chrome, so I'd try disabling them (if possible, I don't use Chrome) to see if that's really the reason. IMO bugs in hardware acceleration are quite possible on 10 years old OS.

Comment: Just posted, needed time to strip out the non-released stuff. It's not that it's 100% secret or anything, it's just our custom CMS system so I had to strip out a bunch of stuff that hasn't been released yet. Confidential wasn't the right word. Posted a link in the question anyway.

Comment: @Rev it is working fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: @JohnIsaacks I had 3 people test it and they all had it here...Had them test the one that's been uploaded as well, same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known Chrome bug:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24524

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20169

If I remove the background image on your page's body tag and also the background on the ul, then the effect stops.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this fix: I use it in a plugin (Lightbox Evolution).

For that specific plugin I use:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){.jquery-lightbox-html{opacity: 0.99 !important;}}
```

If you change the class of a child element with a scrollbar, it will render properly.
This bug happens when any parent has opacity and you have scrollbars on your childrens.